# Create oracle NoSQL table

Tags: oracle, oracle-nosql, nosql

Could anyone please suggest how to create a oracle NoSQL table in the following format

```
column1
column2
column3
column4
column5 
{
    subcolumn1: {date1,date2..dateN}, 
    subcolumn2: N, 
    subcolumn3: 0/1
}
```

Here column5 should in turn have few columns.
I was able to create NoSQL table directly but not in the above mentioned format.
Any suggestion or direction towards appropriate resources is really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do it using a [Record](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/NOSQL/html/GettingStartedGuideTables/tablesapi.html#recordfields) data type for Column 5:

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable IF NOT EXISTS 
    (COLUMN1 STRING, COLUMN2 STRING, COLUMN3 STRING, COLUMN4 STRING, 
    COLUMN5 RECORD(SUBCOLUMN1 ARRAY(LONG), SUBCOLUMN2 STRING, SUBCOLUMN3 BOOLEAN)
)
```

Alternatively, you could use a Child Table ([see the docs here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/NOSQL/html/GettingStartedGuideTables/tablesapi.html#defchildtable)). The main difference being that the Record will always be returned when doing a query on the table whereas the child table would not be fetched by default.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be useful for you to consider using [Child Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57769_01/html/GettingStartedGuideTables/tablesapi.html#defchildtabl) for the **column 5** above.
You can create as many child tables and within that use `Record`, `Map` or **other non-scalar** types to store fields.